# Laplace transformation of $\frac{1-e^{-t}}{t}$

Tags: laplace-transform

Can anybody help me with the Laplace transformation of $$\mathcal{L}\left(\frac{1-e^{-t}}{t}\right)?$$

This was on old exam question, but I can not find a way to solve it.

Comment: Perhaps you could write the function as $t \mapsto \int_0^t e^{-\alpha t} d \alpha$?

Comment: @copper.hat You mean $\int_0^1 e^{-\alpha t} d\alpha$ (I read your mind, I know).

Comment: @Maxim: Thanks!